# Как сверстать блок с разделителями точками без overflow: hidden

Tags: css, вёрстка

Нужно сверстать блок с разделителями точками без overflow: hidden.

Предполагается что в блоке может быть скрытый текст, который нужно показать по наведению на иконку.

Блок с value должен позиционироваться по нижнему краю.

Сложность возникает когда в блоке key мало текста и точки разделители отображаются не там где нужно. Они должны быть продолжением текста key.

Как можно такое реализовать? Или это вообще возможно?

[ДЕМО](https://codepen.io/voronovam/pen/rNredQj)

```css
.key-value-component {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-areas: "key value";
     align-items: start;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     grid-gap: 24px;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     line-height: 2rem;
     position: relative;
}
 .key-value-component__key-content {
     grid-area: key;
     background-color: #fff;
}
 .key-value-component__key-content::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 8px;
     z-index: -1;
     width: 100%;
     height: 16px;
     background-image: radial-gradient(circle, tomato 1px, transparent 0);
     background-size: 0.5ex 2px;
     background-position: bottom;
     background-repeat: space no-repeat;
}
 .key-value-component__value {
     grid-area: value;
     background-color: #fff;
     align-self: end;
}
/* hidden block */
 .tooltip {
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 24px;
     width: 24px;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
 .tooltip:hover .description-content {
     display: block;
}
 .description-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: tomato;
     padding: 8px 16px;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100px;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="key-value-component">
  <div class="key-value-component__key"><span class="key-value-component__key-content">Lorem </span><span class="tooltip"><span class="description-content">BOO!</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="key-value-component__value"><span class="key-value-component__value-content">ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim</span><span class="tooltip"><span class="description-content">BOOO!  </span></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="key-value-component">
  <div class="key-value-component__key"><span class="key-value-component__key-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut</span><span class="tooltip"><span class="description-content">BOO!</span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="key-value-component__value"><span class="key-value-component__value-content">enim ad minim</span><span class="tooltip"><span class="description-content">BOOO!</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В вашем вопросе должен быть минимально воспроизводимый код, код написанный на препроцессорах нужно конвертировать в обычный. Я поправил вопрос.

Comment: в общем, с помощью css это реализовать невозможно. без js не обойтись